# Dirichlet/Neuman conditions for the concentration of oxygen at the interface air-water

Tags: water, boundary-conditions, diffusion

I'd like to compute (with a simulation) the variation of the concentration $c$ ($kg/m^3$) of oxygen in water with a simple diffusion equation :

$$\partial_t c = D\nabla^2 c $$ 
$$c(z=0)=c_0  $$
$$c(t=0)=0 $$

[image]

So my question is how to find $c_0$. I assume $T(air)=293 K$. Since the molar ratio/Volume ratio of oxygen in air is 21%, and that $\rho_{air}=1.292 \;kg/m^3$, I assume $c_0(air)\approx 25\;kg/m^3 $. But is it right to take this value as a Dirichlet condition for water ? And shouldn't Neuman conditions be more adapted ? But how could I write them in that case ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: $c(0)=c_0$ is not a Dirichlet BC, as $c_0$ is a constant. As regards *[...] with a simple diffusion equation :*, problems using the diffusion are rarely simple.

Answer (score 0):

The Dirichlet Boundary condition is actually given by Henry's law which states that the partial pressure in the liquid and in the gaseous phase are equal.